# Use Buttons based on Key Presses instead of Mouse Click

Tags: unity, c#, input, unity-ui

I have a UI button. I want a function to be called whenever I press a specific key on my keyboard while my mouse is hovering over the button. I want to make something similar to UI in Ark SE where you can press 'T' while hovering over an item in your inventory to transfer it.

The button component `OnClick()` has not received keypress input, only mouse clicks.

I am using the **New Unity Input System**

I have tried using a `Raycast` from `ScreenPointToRay` however this did not work as I do not have colliders on my UI and it is part of a `Canvas`.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. I don't think it would be the best but it works for now. With the new input system I subscribe A function (OnTransferKey) to a  Key Press

```
void OnEnable() {
    uI_Manager.uIInputManager.Inventory.OnTransfer.performed += OnTransferKey;
}

void OnDisable() {
    uI_Manager.uIInputManager.Inventory.OnTransfer.performed -= OnTransferKey;
}
```

In the OnTransferKey function I check if the mouse is hovering over the gameObject

```
    bool MouseOverSelf() {
    return EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject();
}


void OnTransferKey(InputAction.CallbackContext obj) {

    if (MouseOverSelf()) {
        print("Do Transfer");
    }
}
```

This works for me for now.
Remember to add `using UnityEngine.EventSystems;`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about the New Unity Input System, but you don't need colliders on your UI objects to raycast them, you just need a Graphic Raycaster component on the canvas, then make sure that the things you want to raycast have the "Raycast Target" box checked like so:
[image: image component with Raycast Target checked]

And then the scripting info you need is [here in Unity's docs.](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.GraphicRaycaster.Raycast.html) That should be all you need let me know if I can help anymore.

Comment: This doesn't appear to answer the part about calling specific functions when particular keyboard keys are pressed while the mouse is over a button.

Comment: In the Unity docs I linked, it includes a script where all you need to do is swap out the key it uses for the key you want to use. I was originally gonna write it out but I realized the docs said it better.